# Undo an earlier change to a single file while there are outstanding local changes in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Every once in a while as I'm working on a local change, I'll realize that I want to undo the change made in a previous revision from a particular file while I'm in the middle of a set of changes. For example:

- r1000 - Changes files A and B
- ... - any number of intermediate changes
- working copy: Outstanding changes to several files

At this point, I realize that I want to completely undo the changes to file A in r1000 as a part of the changes I'm working on.

If I didn't have any local changes, I could use `hg backout`. I've tried using `hg revert -r "1000^" A`, but I get a message about A not being affected by the parent changeset of 1000.

So what's the best way to revert the change from a single file in a previous changeset as a part of my current change?

Answer (score 1):

So as I was writing this up, I ran across the `--reverse` flag on the `hg diff` command. Combining that idea with `hg import` for the example in the question gives a command like:

```
hg diff -c 1000 -I A --reverse | hg import --no-commit --force -
```

This creates a reversed patch of the change in r1000 for the single targeted file, then passes that to `hg import` to be applied to the current working directory without committing.

Comment: +1 cool solution, although personally I'd rather shelve work in progress, `hg backout` the revision, and restore the shelf so the history is clear.